# Cordova video capture event

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am developing an android application using Cordova and Javascript. I include audio/video capturing functionality with function :

```
 navigator.device.capture.captureVideo
```

Everything work fine, but i want to capture the orientation device synchronize with the video. To do that **i need to catch one event when the device start and stop the capture**.

Can anyone suggest me any way to do this?

Comment: have you tried capturing the device orientation first, and then capturing video?